# Create an override of a link with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to make a custom type of link in react which I can use like an a tag but which overrides the onClick to attempt to use a single page app router. It takes a link as props and returns that same link back with the click event overridden.

```
React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        //super naughty but I cant think of a better way of overloading just this
        var oldOnClick = this.props.a._store.props.onClick;
        this.props.a._store.props.onClick = function () {
            if (oldOnClick) {
                oldOnClick();
            }
            router.navigate(this.props.a._store.props.href);
            return false;//always false as were using a router
        }.bind(this);

        return this.props.a;
    }
});
```

This works functionally exactly as expected but its super gross and relies on using private properties of the object. What is the 'right' way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in [Transferring with ... in JSX](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html#transferring-with-...-in-jsx), you can use the the spread operator enabled by the JSX Transformer's `harmony` flag to split out any user-defined `onClick` from the other props, then pass the rest to an `<a>` using [JSX Spread Attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html):

```
var Link = React.createClass({
  _onClick(e) {
    if (this.props.onClick) {
      this.props.onClick()
    }
    e.preventDefault()
    router.navigate(this.props.href)
  },

  render() {
    var {onClick, ...others} = this.props
    return <a {...others} onClick={this._onClick}>{this.props.children}</a>
  }
})
```

Alternatively, you can just configure prop overrides manually, e.g. this is how [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) implements its [`Link` component's `render()`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/e43293d873abb985d4120f33b7955fc5269341fe/modules/components/Link.js#L96-L104), shallow-copying props then overwriting those which need to be configured/handled by the component:

```
  render: function () {
    var props = assign({}, this.props, {
      href: this.getHref(),
      className: this.getClassName(),
      onClick: this.handleClick
    });

    return React.DOM.a(props, this.props.children);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that is much tidier, Its still a little un-ideal as I use plain JS (not jsx) and this requires the use of the React.__spread helper. I think its probably best to just compile this from JSX separate to the rest of my code but it is a bit of a shame I need to.